# implicit declaration of function swab

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, unistd.h

EDIT: the warning in the first paragraph was due to me reading the old log from the compiler (before including unistd.h, sorry for the missconfusion, the second problem still resides)
I have a code that makes use of the c function unlink (declared in unistd.h). Upon compilation with gcc -Wall I get the warning: `implicit declaration of function ‘unlink’` Now I now that this is just a warning but it kinda annoys me and I would like what would be the proper way to resolve this. My current solution is to simply add the line `extern int unlink(const char *path);` to the code but this seems a bit silly as I am also including unistd.h

I used to got a warning about the use of the function swab (also declared in unistd.h) but managed, after inspection of unistd.h, to resolve this by adding the lines

```
#ifndef __USE_XOPEN
#define __USE_XOPEN 
#endif
```

Not sure that this is the proper thing to do so any insights to this would also be appreciated.

Comment: Something is very broken on your system if you have to create an ifdef to use unlink.

Comment: Yup you are probably right, the post is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring your second issue ("implicit declaration of function `sawb`"):

Replace

```
#ifndef __USE_XOPEN
#define __USE_XOPEN 
#endif
```

with

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

... placing it before all other `#include` statements <strike>`#include <unistd.h>`</strike> should make the prototyping for `swab()` be available.

---

`#define`s starting with a double underscore `__` are reserved for internal use and shall not be set by a program directly.

Comment: Hmmm, no good, that just gave me the warning about implicit declaration of swab back

Comment: @cpaitor: Which gcc version and platform are you using? Also please see my updated answer.

Comment: gcc 4.6.2, openuSuSe 12.1, I figured that `__` was not to be used, Oh I also updated my question as the unlink warning was not really there, sorry for that

Comment: @cpaitor: (and alk) You should put feature-test macro definitions (`#define _XOPEN_SOURCE`) before *any* #include, not just before `#include <unistd.h>`. Otherwise it's possible that some other header includes the internal header which defines `swab`, and it will not be included again with the new feature-test setting.

Comment: @rici: that did the trick. A follow up, do I need (or rather should I) to set the value of _XOPEN_SOURCE to some specific value?

Comment: @cpaitor: For swab, no. For other interfaces, possibly; the `man` page for the function call should tell you. (`500` enables Unix98,  `600` enables Posix2001, and `700` enables Posix2008, assuming your standard library implements those interfaces.)

Comment: @rici: Thanks for clarifing what I initially did not mention. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have a typo or something simple wrong.....try this.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
    int r;  

    r = unlink("foo");

    return(r);
}
```

Compile it

```
gcc -Wall foo.c
```

Above should be a clean compile. You can pre-process and do a grep to verify that unlink declaration is pulled in.

```
sys> gcc -E foo.c | grep unlink
int unlink(const char *);
 r = unlink("foo");
```

Comment: Hmmmm, that compiled like a charm. You are probably correct in that there are some problems with the code, I did not write it my-self but am stuck with trying to clean up the mess